# Is there any way to redistribute your skills/perks?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, is there any way to change your skills/perks after you've gotten out of the vault, with or without cheating?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because you don't have any skills/perks when leaving the vault.

You are prompted upon leaving if you which to change your Appearance or your S.P.E.C.I.A.L.

Points in S.P.E.C.I.A.L. unlock perks which also require points to use and upgrade.

You gain one point every level. So you build your perks as you level up, [consult](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/every-special-perk-in-fallout-4/1100-6431989/) [guides](http://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/490123938434666589/) on how to choose your S.P.E.C.I.A.L. if you are going for specific perks/build out of the vault.

There's no known way to redistribute points after the initial prompt after leaving the vault.

However, using console commands on the PC version, you can set your perks and S.P.E.C.I.A.L. to anything you want:

- `player.setav variable amount` - set an actor value to a specific
  amount. `variable` can be a S.P.E.C.I.A.L., such as `strength`, `intelligence` or `endurance`. It can also be `health`, `actionpoints` for running attributes and skills, etc.
- `player.modav variable amount` - modify an actor value; the value will max out at its normal maximum value (100 for skills, 85 for resistances, 10 for S.P.E.C.I.A.L., etc.). A negative number lowers the variable.
- `player.forceav variable amount` - set a value
- `player.advlevel` - advance one level
- `player.setlevel level` - set level

Comment: Should be noted though that the level is not capped and you can eventually unlock everything no gender restricted.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference between `player.setav` and `player.forceav`?

Comment: @Schism If it is still like it was in skyrim, `setav` will "softset" the value, which means that the value which will be set still recognizes other values added by gear or perks, while `forceav` will simply set the value to that, ignoring every other sources you might have. For example: You have 5 agility and you get 2 agility from your armor, now, if you use `player.setav agility 8`, you'll have 10 agility, if you use `player.forceav agility 8`, you'll have 8.

Comment: Don't use forceav, because it will literally stop it from calculating anything properly, including if you later set it with setav - the only known way to stop it is to reload a save

Answer (score 1):

Setav sets the value's real value, like setting setav strength 10 will make the game think you had 10 in SPECIAL strength. modav will add or subtract a kind of "bonus" to it, so if it was 10 and you put modav -1, youll have 10-1 in the game logic. 9 in terms of carryweight and melee damage, but 10 in the SPECIAL perk menu. the way forceav is supposed to work is by adding the proper amount of "modav" bonus to your setav base. setav strength 9, then forceav strength 11 will set you at 9+2 strength - 9 base real strength and a 2 bonus. forceav is glitchy sometimes though.